# logstash tcp input configuration using LogstashTcpSocketAppender

Tags: tcp, logstash, slf4j, logback, appender

I'm new to logstash, elasticsearch and kibana.
I have the following configuration for the logback.xml and logstash.conf files, I'm facing this error:

```html
[2015-06-17 22:47:14,726][INFO ][node                     ] [Brigade] version[1.6.0], pid[7208], build[cdd3ac4/2015-06-09T13:36:34Z]
[2015-06-17 22:47:14,727][INFO ][node                     ] [Brigade] initializing ...
[2015-06-17 22:47:14,731][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Brigade] loaded [], sites []
[2015-06-17 22:47:16,077][INFO ][env                      ] [Brigade] using [1] data paths, mounts [[OS (C:)]], net usable_space [363.9gb], net total_space [452.4gb], types [NTFS]
[2015-06-17 22:47:20,610][INFO ][node                     ] [Brigade] initialized
[2015-06-17 22:47:20,612][INFO ][node                     ] [Brigade] starting ...
[2015-06-17 22:47:21,106][INFO ][transport                ] [Brigade] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.0.19:9300]}
[2015-06-17 22:47:21,495][INFO ][discovery                ] [Brigade] elasticsearch/jiPxp6dpS4GWt7Nd9rui8A
[2015-06-17 22:47:25,399][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Brigade] new_master [Brigade][jiPxp6dpS4GWt7Nd9rui8A][CRTRINTECH01][inet[/192.168.0.19:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-06-17 22:47:25,497][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Brigade] recovered [4] indices into cluster_state
[2015-06-17 22:47:26,067][INFO ][http                     ] [Brigade] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.0.19:9200]}
[2015-06-17 22:47:26,068][INFO ][node                     ] [Brigade] started
[2015-06-17 22:47:59,810][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Brigade] added {[logstash-CRTRINTECH01-1736-7936][59uCFeWxTImZlrlyy2_gpQ][CRTRINTECH01][inet[/192.168.0.19:9301]]{data=false, client=true},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(join from node[[logstash-CRTRINTECH01-1736-7936][59uCFeWxTImZlrlyy2_gpQ][CRTRINTECH01][inet[/192.168.0.19:9301]]{data=false, client=true}])
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,168][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xaee4d9f8, /192.168.0.19:50224 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,170][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xec6423c2, /192.168.0.19:50235 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,172][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x231490be, /192.168.0.19:50228 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,170][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x7d6271fb, /192.168.0.19:50241 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,170][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x1c241c53, /192.168.0.19:50238 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,170][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xf32ef395, /192.168.0.19:50237 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,169][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x2ac88eb2, /192.168.0.19:50227 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,169][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x3472722d, /192.168.0.19:50236 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,169][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x0659d284, /192.168.0.19:50239 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,169][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x0c3047e2, /192.168.0.19:50226 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,169][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x5570cb33, /192.168.0.19:50240 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,169][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x4fe4e2f3, /192.168.0.19:50223 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,281][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x209b3279, /192.168.0.19:50231 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,267][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xcbe7acff, /192.168.0.19:50234 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,243][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Brigade] removed {[logstash-CRTRINTECH01-1736-7936][59uCFeWxTImZlrlyy2_gpQ][CRTRINTECH01][inet[/192.168.0.19:9301]]{data=false, client=true},}, reason: zen-disco-node_failed([logstash-CRTRINTECH01-1736-7936][59uCFeWxTImZlrlyy2_gpQ][CRTRINTECH01][inet[/192.168.0.19:9301]]{data=false, client=true}), reason transport disconnected
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,175][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x9b3d6f83, /192.168.0.19:50243 => /192.168.0.19:9301]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-06-17 22:49:02,175][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Brigade] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xd650c49b, /192.168.0.19:50232 => /192.168.0.19:9300]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the configuration of the logback.xml file

```html
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
   <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender>
   
   <appender name="STASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <remoteHost>localhost</remoteHost>
        <port>4560</port>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
    </appender>
 
 <root level="ALL">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  <appender-ref ref="STASH" />
 </root>
</configuration>
```

Here is the logstash configuration

```html
input {
 tcp {
  port => 4560
  host => "localhost"
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch { 
  host => "localhost"
  port => 9300
  index => "closecompliance"
  manage_template => false
 }
 stdout {
 }
}
```

And I uncommented the line related to transport.tcp.port: 9300 from the elasticsearch.yxml.

Also if I change the input from the logstash.conf file to be stdin instead of tcp I'm able to see the information in Kibana.
I'm using slf4j for logging.

Here is the main class I am running

```html
package com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbackexample;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class BasicConfApp {
 final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicConfApp.class);
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  logger.info("Msg #1");
  logger.warn("Msg #2");
  logger.error("Msg #3");
  logger.debug("Msg #4");
 }
}
```

Thanks for all the help you can provide on this.

Regards,

Comment: Try   elasticsearch {
    ...
    protocol => "http"
    port => 9200
  }